# Rails 4.2.6 - Devise 4.2.2 - Default Auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-page-application

I am looking to set a secondary password by which I can authenticate a user for a login as from admin. The reason for this work around is the front end is a single page application.

Each user has been given a unique login_as string. now I need to configure Devise to compare the login_as if the password fails.

Any help is appreciated. I am of course open to an alternative solution if there is a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](https://insights.kyan.com/devise-authentication-strategies-a1a6b4e2b891#.arimvcdjy) from Duncan Robertson was very helpful in solving my issue. I essentially created an override strategy and called it in the devise.rb file. I had some concern regarding tampering with a large user base but it has proved successful. By adding a column to users named ":signin_as" and then setting it to a default unique string with a rake I then had what I needed to fallback on if the initial sign in failed.

the override strategy (config/initializers/auth_override.rb)

```
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class AuthOverride < Authenticatable
      def custom_auth(user, signin_as)
        if user[:signin_as] == signin_as
          return true
        else
          return false
        end
      end
      def authenticate!
        user = User.find_by_email(email)
        if user
          if user.valid_password?(params[:password])
            success!(user)
          elsif custom_auth(user, params[:password])
            success!(user)
          else
            fail
          end
        else        
          fail
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

including the strategy in devise (config/initializers/devise.rb)

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :auth_override
end
```